# python redis update complex objects (nested) (HMSET)

Tags: python, redis

suppose we have this dict object called my_dict:

```
my_dict = {"a": "66", "b": "22", "c": "2321"}
```

so we need to store it in Redis as string object (key, value ):

```
redis_client.hmset("my_dict", str(my_dict))
```

so far so good, but is it possible to **directly** update the keys inside "my_dict"?

something like this :

```
## try to update b property directly"
redis_client.hmset("my_dict.b", "999")
```

maybe this question is duplicated but I couldn't find an exact answer for updating the content inside a nested string object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't stringify the mapping you pass to `hmset`; it's not going to do what you want.

If you do

```
redis_client.hmset("my_dict", {"a": "66", "b": "22", "c": "2321"})
```

you'll have [a hash-type object](https://redis.io/commands#hash) called `my_dict` in Redis, which you can access element-wise:

```
redis_client.hget("my_dict", "a")  # 66
redis_client.hset("my_dict", "a", 67)  # set to 67
```

Comment: tnx for reply , is it possible to use client.incr('my_dict.b', 1) ?

Comment: You're looking for https://redis.io/commands/hincrby in that case.